# Phonegap no architecture issue when build

Tags: iphone, macos, iphone-sdk-3.0, cordova

I am new to iPhone development and I use Phonegap since I know web development. I followed instruction in below sites:
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494778/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-%28iOS%29
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/blob/master/README.md

But I got this error

No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386 ppc, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7).

I already went to Project Setting and changed Base SDK to iPhone Device 3.1.3 but the problem is still there.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

set the "valid archictectures" in Project Info

Comment: I already had Project Settings | Architectures as Optimized (armv6 armv7). I tried to play around and still the same. What is wrong? It is never to get started with Mac/iOS development.

Comment: both project settings, those for you project and those for the phoneGap project

Answer (score 1):

Had the same prob. 
If testing in the simulator: Click top left where you can choose the simulator and check if the top item "Device" is checked. If yes ckeck "Simulator" and try again.